# view all windows in Mavericks keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, finder

In Mavericks (and any other version of OSX) when pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> you see the typical list of open apps to switch to.

I just discovered that when this list is open (before releasing <kbd>CMD</kbd>) if you press <kbd>1</kbd> you see all the windows of currently the selected app.

[image]

What is this feature called?
Is it possible to use it outside of the <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this feature is called "Application Windows". If you go to System Settings -> Mission Control, in the bottom section is a list of four items you can attach to keyboard shortcuts. This feature is called "Application windows" in that list.

Additionally, you can enable a Hot Corner for it: Click the Hot Corners button in the bottom left of the Mission Control settings; you should be able to specify a special action for moving your mouse into each corner of your screen. This feature is called "Application Windows" in the list of options.

Answer (score -1):

You can also configure hot corner to achieve this.

Comment: Can you add some details on how to accomplish this with hot corners? Not everybody reading your answer might be familiar with the concept.